# Type ViewController doesn't conform to protocol UITableViewData Source

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I created this program but I have this persisting problem that my ViewController doesn't conform to `UITableViewDataSource`. I don't know what else to do. I looked everywhere in the forums.
Can you spot any problem?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate,  UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {
    struct MyData {
        var imagy:UIImage
        var title:String
        var details:String
    }

    var tableData: [MyData] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var mapItemData:MKMapItem!

    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
        sender: AnyObject?){
            // Set any data to be shown on the table view here
    }

    var picture:[UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "pic1.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic2.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic3.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic4.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic5.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic6.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic7.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic8.jpg")!,    ]

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       // var imageView : UIImageView
       // imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 300));
       // imageView.image = UIImage(named:"image.jpg")
       // self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        tableData = [
            MyData(imagy:UIImage(named: "pic1.jpg")! ,title: "The first row", details: "Hello"),
        ]

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

         mapView.delegate = self

        let J = Shops(title: "Jingle", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.631076, longitude: 22.946770), info: "H", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
        let K = Shops(title: "R", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.65, longitude: 6.43), info: "F", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
        let L = Shops(title: "P", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 58.89, longitude: 2.3508), info: "O", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
        let B = Shops(title: "R", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 26, longitude: 17), info: "H", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
        let W = Shops(title: "W", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 88.43111, longitude: -37.035663), info: "N", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")

        mapView.addAnnotations([J, K, L, B, W])
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

            func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
                if let annotation = annotation as? Shops{
                    let identifier = "pin"
                    var view: MKPinAnnotationView
                    if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
                        as? MKPinAnnotationView {
                            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
                            view = dequeuedView
                    } else {

                        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                        view.canShowCallout = true
                        view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)

                        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure) as UIView
                    }
                    return view
                }
                return nil
           }

    // Initiate GPS
    func fitMapViewToAnnotaionList(annotations: [MKPointAnnotation]) -> Void {
        let mapEdgePadding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
        var zoomRect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectNull

        for index in 0..<annotations.count {
            let annotation = annotations[index]
            let aPoint:MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
            let rect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectMake(aPoint.x, aPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1)

            if MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect) {
                zoomRect = rect
            } else {
                zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, rect)
            }

            // Locate through GPS

            func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
                let location = locations.last
                let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

                self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }

        //Pressing Button and segue
            func Button(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl){
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("TableViewCell", sender: self)
            }

        //TableViewDataSource functions
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return tableData.count
        }

        func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{}

        func table(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            // Create a new cell with the reuse identifier of our prototype cell
            // as our custom table cell class
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell") as! TableViewController
            // Set the first row text label to the firstRowLabel data in our current array item
            cell.imagy.image = tableData[indexPath.row].imagy
            // Set the second row text label to the secondRowLabel data in our current array item
            cell.title.text = tableData[indexPath.row].title
            // Set the second row text label to the secondRowLabel data in our current array item
            cell.details.text = tableData[indexPath.row].details
            // Return our new cell for display
            return cell

            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `numberOfSectionsInTableView()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I know, I just put it there because I read it in another topic in Stack, where the guy had the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch out for the {} and indentation: your tableView datasource methods are nested within the `fitMapViewToAnnotaionList` method.  Move them out of that method into the class itself.

Also, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is implemented as

```
func table(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

which should be:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

As others have said, `numberOfSectionsInTableView` should return an value; you probably want 1 (or delete the method completely; it's not required by the protocol).

So this should get rid of the problem with conforming to the protocol (though there may be other unrelated problems):

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate,  UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {
    struct MyData {
        var imagy:UIImage
        var title:String
        var details:String
    }

    //TableViewDataSource functions
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{ return 1 }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Create a new cell with the reuse identifier of our prototype cell
        // as our custom table cell class
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell") as! TableViewController
        // Set the first row text label to the firstRowLabel data in our current array item
        cell.imagy.image = tableData[indexPath.row].imagy
        // Set the second row text label to the secondRowLabel data in our current array item
        cell.title.text = tableData[indexPath.row].title
        // Set the second row text label to the secondRowLabel data in our current array item
        cell.details.text = tableData[indexPath.row].details
        // Return our new cell for display
        return cell

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    var tableData: [MyData] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var mapItemData:MKMapItem!

    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
        sender: AnyObject?){
            // Set any data to be shown on the table view here
    }

    var picture:[UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "pic1.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic2.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic3.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic4.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic5.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic6.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic7.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "pic8.jpg")!,    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // var imageView : UIImageView
        // imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 300));
        // imageView.image = UIImage(named:"image.jpg")
        // self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        tableData = [
            MyData(imagy:UIImage(named: "pic1.jpg")! ,title: "The first row", details: "Hello"),
        ]

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        mapView.delegate = self

        let J = Shops(title: "Jingle", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.631076, longitude: 22.946770), info: "H", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
        let K = Shops(title: "R", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.65, longitude: 6.43), info: "F", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
        let L = Shops(title: "P", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 58.89, longitude: 2.3508), info: "O", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
        let B = Shops(title: "R", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 26, longitude: 17), info: "H", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")
        let W = Shops(title: "W", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 88.43111, longitude: -37.035663), info: "N", address:"Π", subtitle:"κ")

        mapView.addAnnotations([J, K, L, B, W])
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if let annotation = annotation as? Shops{
            let identifier = "pin"
            var view: MKPinAnnotationView
            if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
                as? MKPinAnnotationView {
                    dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
                    view = dequeuedView
            } else {

                view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                view.canShowCallout = true
                view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)

                view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure) as UIView
            }
            return view
        }
        return nil
    }

    // Initiate GPS
    func fitMapViewToAnnotaionList(annotations: [MKPointAnnotation]) -> Void {
        let mapEdgePadding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
        var zoomRect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectNull

        for index in 0..<annotations.count {
            let annotation = annotations[index]
            let aPoint:MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
            let rect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectMake(aPoint.x, aPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1)

            if MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect) {
                zoomRect = rect
            } else {
                zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, rect)
            }

            // Locate through GPS

            func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
                let location = locations.last
                let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

                self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }

        //Pressing Button and segue
        func Button(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl){
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("TableViewCell", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I changed the {} and even moved the whole thing up in a different spot, but the problem persists. 
I also changed the function to "tableView"

Comment: I put the whole package of "Table View Functions" first thing under "Struct MyData" just to make sure it is within the class, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @ChrisVlachos I've added amended code which compiles OK for me.